# sample project documentations

Tags: documentation, uml, sample

I am a fresher as developer in java. I was assigned a full real project(bug trackin project). Now I have to prepare the UML diagrams for my project. I know abt UML diagrams, but I wish to see as many samples and examples before Drawing the UML for my project. So that I can prepare a very perfect documentation.

Is there any site links were I can see many real time projects scenario with their documentation. So that I can get some idea of how experts are thinking, and get some ideas and style.

Comment: documentation in the sense .. the Class diagrams, sequence diagram, use case diagrams etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what ever the links you refer, you never get clear Idea. Because always you get just the theory part. My suggestion is to talk to your seniors or HOD's and get the previous documnets. First refer them then refer the sites.

You can google the **latest IEEE format** for software document. Even I was a fresher just last year and its my experience than, what ever the latest document you prepare, your faulties will always match it will old one. So first get Idea from old docs then refer new one. follow the guidelines of your project guide.

All the best.

Microsoft Visio, Umbrella, Rational rose etc are good software for UML designing.

Answer (score 1):

[here is a link to a uml-project-documentation](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-project-documentation.html)

some other uml guides

[link1](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlClassDiagrams.pdf)

[link2](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml-tutorial.html)

[link3](http://www.visualcase.com/tutorials/uml-tutorial.htm)